# C# double for loop stringbuilder if condition is met

Tags: c#, for-loop, stringbuilder

having following code:

```
for (float y = 575; y > ascisse[i]; y -= 9.6f)
{
  for (int x = 105; x <= 320; x += 10)
  {
    var text = TextByCoord(new Coord { X = x, Y = y, Page = page });

    if (text == "") continue;

    if (lastText == null)
       lastText = text;
    else if (lastText == text) continue;
       lastText = text;
       textLine = text;
  }

  if (textLine.Equals("DESTINAZIONE MERCE"))
  {
    Console.WriteLine(lastText);
    stringBuilder.Append(lastText + " ");
    continue;
  }

  if (textLine.Equals("******************"))
  {
    break;
  }
}
```

What code is doing is scanning the PDF file for a text fields. 
What I need to achieve is: for the specified Y-scale (ascisse[i]) I'm scanning each row starting from initial Y coordinate which is 575. So, If in the row I met "DESTINAZIONE MERCE" so I need to append that to the StringBuilder, then I need to append the next values before ******************.

Here is the example of the content:

- DESTINAZIONE MERCE
- XXXX SPA
- XXXX SPA
- VIA XXXX, XI
- 99999 XXXXXX XX
- "****************"

So, my output should be : DESTINAZIONE MERCE XXXX SPA XXXX SPA VIA XXXX, XI 99999 XXXXXX XX

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: The question is how I can append the text between DESTINAZIONE MERCE (this value I need to append too to the StringBuilder) and "*******************"

Comment: why do you only need text below 575 and which pdf library are you using?

Comment: actually it's a custom API released by my company. I need it for an enterprise proposes. Basically PDF is composed by two columns. First column contains productID and in the other column contains product description and other data. 
So, before the "*****************" I need concatenate the data mentioned in the question. After the "*******" there is a product description.

Comment: in fact what I'm doing is starting from the 575 which is start-poing for scanning I'm scanning the second column for the data until I reach the the Y-coordinate of the productID (ascisse[i]).

Comment: What I must to do, is once in the second column I met the value DESTINAZIONE MERCE, I need to append it to StringBuilder then append all other rows until I reach the asteriscs.

Comment: It seems like you want to shift "****..." couple lines later. A dirty flag should do the work.

Comment: @LouisGo no, I want to concat the string before the "******".